# Fatal Error occurred after trying to export unsigned android application

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I tried to export unsigned application from Eclipse to get the release file, it keeps giving me `Fatal Error Code 1` with these details :

P.S we are using Twitter4J library while we do not use anything related to Facebook.

```
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.android.Facebook$ServiceListener
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Session$StatusCallback
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.parse.auth.FacebookAuthenticationProvider$2$1: can't find superclass or interface com.facebook.Request$Callback
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find superclass or interface javax.management.DynamicMBean
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b: can't find referenced method 'android.view.Display getDisplay()' in class android.view.View
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b: can't find referenced method 'void removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver$OnGlobalLayoutListener)' in class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.android.Facebook
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils: can't find referenced class com.facebook.Session

......

[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: there were 203 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-05-17 13:16:07 - Faltirha]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

**EDIT:**
 I was able to export the unsigned application by commenting this in the project-properties file

> proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project‌​.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt

but I think this is not the solution!

Comment: Check your Logcat what it says :
1. **You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.** 
2. **There were 203 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.**
3. **You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').**
Definately, you missed to attach jar file, may be twitter4j jar file. Please put it in lib  folder and build path.

Comment: @ManishAndroid Thanks for your prompt reply, the prob is actually I didn't get the 3 steps u mentioned, and I'm pretty sure that the Twitter4J library is in the libs folder

Comment: Check **Configure Build Path** Section. Is there any red-cross on any library ?

Comment: @ManishAndroid I just checked but there isn't any red-cross on any library

Comment: Solutions will be to ignore warnings as they are internal to lib projects. Add **-dontwarn packagename** in progaurd file.

Comment: @ManishAndroid I've added `-dontwarn "MyPackageName"` to the project properties file, but the same error occurred

Comment: @ManishAndroid Thanks for ur help I became able to export the unsigned application by commenting this `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt`

Comment: Glad to help. Post this in Answer section and accept it as best answer for those developer who will face this problem in future. At that time, your answer will be helpful for them.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to overcome this exact issue by adding the line

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

to my proguard-project.txt file.

Comment: I had similar problems after adding google-play-services_lib to our Eclipse project which has android:minSdkVersion 9. E.g. we got the warning about android.content.ComponentCallbacks2 because that is available only in API 14. I'm assuming this is similar to other google libs such as AdMob which do run time checking of API version so these version dependencies can be safely ignored

Answer (score 0):

I was able to export the unsigned application by commenting this (below) in the project-properties file

> proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project‌​.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt

but I think this is not the proper solution!

Answer (score 0):

No, the solution is not to comment it in the project properties file unless you dont care about encrypting your apk.  If you don't care about someone decrypting your code, go ahead and remove it from the project properties file.